# Folland's proof of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have difficulty in understanding two steps in Folland's proof of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem:

[image]

The lemmas it uses are:

( It is given that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subalgebra of $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ that separates points)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Then the proof says:
[image]

As highlighted above, I do not understand why lemma 4.48 and 4.49 can imply $\mathcal{A} = C(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{A}=\{f\in C(X,\mathbb{R}): f(x_0)=0\}$ in two situations. Specifically,

1. Lemma 4.38 implies $\mathcal{A}$ is a lattice, while lemma 4.39 requires $\mathcal{A}$ to be a **closed** lattice to deduce the expected conclusions. How to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed lattice?
2. In the second highlighted case, assuming lemma 4.39 holds, how to use it to get the conclusion?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Lemma $4.48$ takes a *closed* subalgebra, so unless closed lattice has a different meaning than just a lattice that is closed, $\mathcal{A}$ was already closed.

Comment: For the second highlighted part, assume that $f\in C(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $f(x_0)=0$. Let $y\in X$ such that $f(y)\neq0$. If no such $y$ exists, then $f\equiv0\in A$ already. We have that $A_{x_0y}$ is generated by $(0,1)$ Take $g\in A$ such that $(g(x_0),g(y))=(0,1)$. Then we can take $f(y)g$ to be the $g_{x_0y}$ in Lemma 4.49. This implies that $f\in A$. So $\{f\in C(X,\mathbb{R}):\ f(x_0)=0\}\subset A$. The reverse inclusion is being assumed at that point of the proof.

Comment: @NDB I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BrunoB Got it. Thank you very much!